# How do i write an xpath for linktext

Tags: xpath

Hi i would like to know how to write xpath for linktext

I did try the following ones

```
//a[text()='text_i_want_to_find']/@href

//*[@linktext='text_i_want_to_find']
```

but they don seem to work,my intention in doing this is to select a specific value  from a drop down. could you pls help me on this?

Comment: Please show us a sample of what you are running those xpaths against.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for an HTML document, your first attempt looks ok except I'd use `normalize-space` to trim the element's text, eg

```
//a[normalize-space(text())='text I want to find']/@href
```

This is especially useful of your element looks like this

```
<a href="foo">
    text I want to find
</a>
```

`normalize-space` will trim the whitespace (newlines, spaces, tabs, etc) around the text.